# Mil'al vs. Milra on "Lamah"

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, trop-cantillation

In a few places in the Torah, the word למה is pronounced מלעיל (accent on 1st syllable) and in other places מלרע (accent on 2nd syllable.)

I viewed [Bemidbar 11:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=128) which has both in the same verse. The 1st one has a *mahpach* under the word is מלרע , and the 2nd has a *tevir* and is מלעיל . The 2nd is not a case of נסוג אחור.

Is there a difference in meaning with these two versions, and if so, what is it? Otherwise, what are the rules governing which one is used? Does it have to do with the trope note?

Comment: I don't recall the source (may have been R' Hirsch - will check), but I have learned that according to one opinion, there's a subtle distinction in meaning: the מלרע version is ~"to what end" while the מלעיל one is ~"stemming from what motivation."

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87278/whats-the-difference-in-meaning-between-lamah-and-maduah

Comment: There's also [לָמֶה](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.1.8?lang=he).  It's mileeil, but no dageish.

Comment: Slightly related, but good Purim Torah fun:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69396/which-side-was-the-llama-of-yetziat-mitzrayim-on

Comment: What does נסוג אחור mean?

Comment: @DonielF See my question related to this - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43336/5275. In that question, there's a link to a Hebrew Wikipedia article. My question gives a brief summary of what it is. The technique is extremely common in Torah reading, and seems to be common in Tefillah as well. Consider *Birkat Hatorah* - *Asher BOchar banu..." - normally the word is pronounced *boCHAR*, but b/c the next word is *BAnu*, the previous word's accent moves back 1 syllable.

Answer (score 8):

The word is spelled לָמָה (without a dagesh and stressed on the final syllable) when the following word begins with an א or ה or ע,* and spelled לָמָּה (with a dagesh and stressed on the penultimate syllable) in every other case.

There are eight exceptions to these rules (enumerated in [Masora Gedola to Psalms 43:2](https://archive.org/stream/The_Second_Rabbinic_Bible_Vol_4/4#page/n38/mode/1up)): The three cases of לָמָה before letters other than אה"ע are Psalms 42:20, 43:2, and Job 7:20 (the latter case is also exceptional in being pronounced with penultimate stress despite not having a dagesh). The five cases of לָמָּה before אה"ע are II Samuel 14:31, Psalms 49:6, Jeremiah 15:18, I Samuel 28:15, II Samuel 2:22.

<sub>* Judging by the transcription [here](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/27/43/2/mg/71), it should be read אה"ע and not אח"ע. Masora Gedola to 49:6 says א"ה, but in [this transcription](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/27/49/6/mg/71) it says אה"ע again, which is evidently more correct.</sub>

Comment: Any insight on https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.1.8?lang=he?

Comment: @Heshy I don't know why, and the Masora and commentators are also strangely silent

Comment: @Heshy Is the question why it’s with a Segol, or why it’s on the penultimate syllable in spite of not having a dagesh in the Mem and the following word not beginning with an Aleph or Hei?

Comment: @DonielF both [15]

Comment: In this example the next word starts with ע: https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.15.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Kazibácsi Good point, I had assumed א"ה was correct because all the exceptions were with א or ה, but I guess not. I'll try to figure out a better explanation of the rule (and also hopefully to figure out why it doesn't just say אהח"ע)

Comment: @ba Initially I thought that this was a _nasog achor_ issue, so I looked them up in the concordance, and there are a few without א and ה.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I think I got it right this time. Apparently I just misread (or it was misprinted) אח"ע instead of אה"ע

Comment: See this on p. 186: https://www.openbookpublishers.com/books/10.11647/obp.0194